# Using a variable value inside Tkinter - AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Having a bit of an issue with Tkinter.

I am wanting to use a JSON file to act as a "config" to assign the frame of a widget.

My JSON parser is:

```
 with open('data.txt') as json_file:
 data = json.load(json_file)
 for p in data['config']:
 clockFrame = (p['clockFrame'])
 clockSide = (p['clockSide'])
```

and when running tests via using print clockFrame it produces the value that I want "self.topFrame"

This line of code works as intended:

```
self.clock = clock.Clock(self.topFrame)
```

However when I want to use the variable such as:

```
self.clock = clock.Clock(clockFrame)
```

It ends up giving me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Anyone know what is the best way to call the variable so that I am using the value?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please check if `self.topFrame` and `clockFrame` have same type.

Comment: What is `clock.Clock` and what are its initialization parameters? You read a string from the json configuration. Does that match the call signature of `Clock`?

Comment: As an aside, you appear to be using python 2.x which is at end of life. Consider upgrading to python 3.

Comment: @tdelaney Will look into porting the code over to Python 3. In terms of the code there should be nothing inside clock that will be related to this.

self.topFrame = Frame(self.tk, background = 'black')

Is the code for topFrame. The JSON is just clockFrame: "self.topFrame"

Comment: That is a strange way to do a configuration. Its not `self.topFrame` just a string "self.topFrame" that you will have to associate with your frame object somehow. Can you change the json config? Suppose it was just "topFrame", then you could `self.clock = clock.Clock(getattr(self, clockFrame))`

Comment: @Vacation ***"use a JSON file to act as a "config" to assign the frame of a widget."***: Do you write a `tkinter` object to `.json` and want to rebuild the object doing `json.load(...`? [Edit] your question code per the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: @tdelaney Worked a treat! thank you!

Comment: The indentation of your first code block needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to configure which widget gets the clock. Since you are storing a string you need some way of mapping that string to a frame object. You've got the right idea, you want `self.topFrame` in this case. Since the object's member data is already a named database of sorts, you can just change the configuration to the name of the variable holding the object you want.

```
with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    # this loops through a list of configs and keeps the last
    # one, which is odd..
    for p in data['config']:
        clockFrame = (p['clockFrame'])
        clockSide = (p['clockSide'])

     # in this example, clockFrame = "topFrame"

# get clock frame from current object data
self.clock = clock.Clock(getattr(self, clockFrame))
```